# UITextField Number Pad not working

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

```
_text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _text.font = [Styles bodyFont];
        _text.text = ((EditTextBubble *)(toEdit.bubble)).textLabel.text;
        if ([_text.text isEqualToString:[@"E.g. " stringByAppendingString:((EditTextBubble *)toEdit.bubble).placeholder]]) _text.text = @"";
        _text.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        _text.delegate = self;
        _text.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self addSubview:_text];
_text.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

I'm trying to get the number pad (http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/keypad.png) to work for UITextField but all I get is the normal keyboard on the numbers page, not that google image above. How do you get it to work? This is on iOS 7 and on ipod/ipad, and without the nib file.

Comment: The keyboard in your screenshot only appears on the iPhone or iPod touch. On an iPad you will get the full keyboard.

Comment: So i have to make my own numpad?

Comment: No, the full iPad keyboard shows the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to display a numpad keyboard on iPad, you will need to build your own (or use an [open source](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/numberpad)), and set the text view's `inputView` to the view you created. But don't be alarmed, this is quite easy to do.

On iOS7, use `UIInputView` to get a similar look and background to the native keyboard.

An example of Apple's custom numeric keyboard on iPad in their Numbers app:

[image]

Comment: So thats how they did that.